# JS: how to use a returned object in other class functions?

Tags: javascript

**CustomPlayer**

```
import videojs from 'videojs';

class CustomPlayer {
    construct(htmlElement, customConfig) {
          this.htmlElement = htmlElement;
          this.customConfig = customConfig;
    }

    init() {
       let player = videojs(htmlElement,customConfig);
       return player;
    }
    
    setBitrate() {
      ??
    }
}

export default CustomPlayer;
```

how I was using this is as follows in a JS file:

```
let myPlayer = new CustomerPlay('element-id', customConfigData).init();

myPlayer // video JS object from my CustomPlayer since `init()` returns `player`
```

I want to now be able to call `setBitrate()` and have access to the `player` that was init'd.  How can I do that without passing in the player into setBitrate?  Ideally, I wanted to call it on player like:

```
let myPlayer = new CustomerPlay('element-id', customConfigData).init();
myPlayer.setBitrate();
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `init`, you've got the constructor already:

```
class CustomPlayer {
    construct(htmlElement, customConfig) {
        this.htmlElement = htmlElement;
        this.customConfig = customConfig;

        // "this.player", not "let player"!
        this.player = videojs(htmlElement, customConfig); 
    }

    setBitrate() {
        this.player.whatEver...
    }
}

let myPlayer = new CustomerPlay('element-id', customConfigData);
myPlayer.setBitrate();
```

Comment: if I don't return `player` somehow, the value of of `myPlayer` will be just be the class Object.  I need to return the player that is created (`this.player`) so that is is a videojs object

Comment: if you work with raw player objects, why do you need your class then?

Comment: there are 2 other players in this file.  I have to create a 3rd player, which is different, and I am trying to extract it into its own class for readability.  I'm open to other ways though :)

Comment: @benntyGoodla: it would be a good idea to edit your question and add more context and code samples. Right now I don't quite understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your variable player as a public variable/property of your class or initiate it inside your constructor as an empty object, this way you can access the variable from any class functions you declare.

```
class CustomPlayer {
    let player = {};// first option
    construct(htmlElement, customConfig) {
        this.player = {};//second option
        this.htmlElement = htmlElement;
        this.customConfig = customConfig;
    }
    init() {
        this.player = videojs(htmlElement,customConfig);
        return this.player;
    }
    //useful getter
    getPlayer(){
        return this.player;
    }

    a(){
      //can access variable player

    b(){
      //can access variable player
    }
...
```

Comment: thanks Mike! How would you use that `getPlayer()` getter?

Comment: just as you used init
`let cp       = new CustomerPlay('element-id', customConfigData);
 let player = cp.getPlayer();//empty object before cp.init()`